# How can I clean this requests result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, filter, python-requests

I am working with a web API(`film API`). When I make a post request using requests to a certain URL I get this response:

```
<a href='\"https:\/\/xdede.co\/peliculas\/p284052-ver-doctor-strange-online\"' up-target='\"body\"'>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t
<div class='\"SPoster\"'>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
<img src='\"https:\/\/image.tmdb.org\/t\/p\/w45\/7OpmunCEZo93nyRIbx59QRaFvZz.jpg\"'/>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t&lt;\/div&gt;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t
<h2>Doctor Strange&lt;\/h2&gt;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span>Pelicula&lt;\/span&gt;\n\t\t\t\t\t&lt;\/a&gt;\n\t\t\t\t&lt;\/div&gt;\n\t\t\t\t"}</span>
</h2></div></a>
```

How can I filter this mess to get the `href` and the `h2` tag? I've tried `beautifulsoup` but nothing. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` and `regex`

```
import re

import bs4 as bs4

html = """<a href='\"https:\/\/xdede.co\/peliculas\/p284052-ver-doctor-strange-online\"' up-target='\"body\"'>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class='\"SPoster\"'>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src='\"https:\/\/image.tmdb.org\/t\/p\/w45\/7OpmunCEZo93nyRIbx59QRaFvZz.jpg\"'/>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t&lt;\/div&gt;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<h2>Doctor Strange&lt;\/h2&gt;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span>Pelicula&lt;\/span&gt;\n\t\t\t\t\t&lt;\/a&gt;\n\t\t\t\t&lt;\/div&gt;\n\t\t\t\t"}</span></h2></div></a>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

href = re.sub(r'[\\"]', '', soup.a['href'])
h2 = re.sub(r'<[^>]*>', '', soup.a.h2.text)
h2 = ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)', h2))

print(href)
print(h2)
```

Output:

```
https://xdede.co/peliculas/p284052-ver-doctor-strange-online
Doctor Strange Pelicula
```